# Staging files to multiple locations in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have three choice parameters in my pipeline script. If I select one parameter QA1, Hold_Area is able to save it as **Hold_Area** =QA1 and respective stage step is working fine.

If I want to copy my files to two places likes QA1 and JUT2, If developer selects QA1, JUT2 from Jenkins console **Hold_Area** is holding QA1, JUT2.

Staging step is failing since expression is failing.

What is the best way I can stage files to multiple locations when developers select more than one choice?

```
extendedChoice(description: 'Please select hold area', multiSelectDelimiter: ',', name: '**Hold_Area**', quoteValue: false, saveJSONParameterToFile: false, type: 'PT_CHECKBOX', value: 'QA1,QA2,JUT2', visibleItemCount: 3)
```

```
stage ('Coyping files to QA1') {
    when {
        expression { params.Hold_Area == 'QA1' }
    }
    steps {
        echo "Files copying to hold area QA1!"
    }
}
stage ('Coyping files to QA2') {
    when {
        expression { params.Hold_Area == 'QA2' }
    }
    steps {
        echo "Files copying to hold area QA2!"
    }
}

stage ('Coyping files to JUT2') {
    when {
        expression { params.Hold_Area == 'JUT2' }
    }
    steps {
        echo "Files copying to hold area JUT2!"
    }
}
```

Groovy scripting logic for Jenkins pipeline project.